# Model design in Django. Is South the only way to have any bit of freedom in changes in model?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Hi I am newbie to django development, but anyway I will try in this question do not to be generall.

I have strange problems while designing my model. I want to make a lot of changes - like alwyas in the begining of the project. **The problem is that after one syncdb I can not change anything in model, unless I create completly new database and link it in settings.py.** What is pretty strange I even can not delete this old database. When I try do it from Sequel Pro it freezes.

**I googled a bit, and is really South or similar tool the only option to have some fredoom in models desgining phase in django?**

I know that this mechanisms are for certain purpose like keeping data consistency on existing project, but I just started my development and have even 0 records in all the tables.

I user in my development 5.6.13 MySQL Community Server, Django 1.5. All runing on OS X.

Comment: please comment instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

South is a great tool for migration or if you have made some changes. It may take a little time to get through for the beginners as it was for me too, but eventually you will like it. Other than that as per your question, you can use `flush`, which replaced `reset` in django 1.5. And please remember, that it flush all the database and not just the app.

```
python manage.py flush
```

But luckily `reset` has been ported back in [here](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-reset). All you have to do is install, and add it in the settings. And then run

```
python manage.py reset appname
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: thanks to reset I managed to delete the old database. But only the previous. The current NOT. By the way are this db somehow locked by django for being edited e.g from some db managment systems like SequelPro?

Comment: I think you mean, that reset was replaced by flush in 1.5?

Comment: Yes, `reset` was replaced by the `flush`. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Partially I found answer here: [Django: Change models without clearing all data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746818/django-change-models-without-clearing-all-data/2746865#2746865)

SAYING: "**syncdb will only create tables for models which have not yet been installed. It will never issue ALTER TABLE statements to match changes made to a model class after installation.** Changes to model classes and database schemas often involve some form of ambiguity and, in those cases, Django would have to guess at the correct changes to make. There is a risk that critical data would be lost in the process. If you have made changes to a model and wish to alter the database tables to match, use the sql command to display the new SQL structure and compare that to your existing table schema to work out the changes."

OK. I see that I can run `python manage.py sql <app_name>` then should I paste it in `python manage.py dbshell`?

via dbshell I managed to delete whole database, what was not possible in Sequel Pro.

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

and then via MySQL:

```
drop database <db_name>;
```

And why the database when accesing from Sequel Pro is froozen?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to avoid South, because there were many opinions that it is confusing, and time consuming to learn. After sometime I look back on SOUTH and I have to say:

1. It is completely WORTH learning it, what is not hard at all.
2. It is very nice tool for dealing with model, which changes dynamically.

I can propose a nice tutorial video to all newbies, who will consider either it is or not worth to learn. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yCmAhthkMk